# It doesnt change property,which is binded(mode TwoWay)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have text box,i binded its Text property to MainTxtBoxTxt property in ModalView of Window.When MainTxtBoxTxt changes it affects to TextBox,but when Text property of TextBox changes it doesnt affect to MainTxtBoxTxt in ModelView.What is the problem?

```
<cstmTxtBox:CustomTextBox Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" x:Name="TxtBox" cstmTxtBox:CustomTextBox.CaretIndex="{Binding Path=CaretIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Path=MainTxtBoxText,Mode=TwoWay}"   >
```

**CustomTxtBox**

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {

        public CustomTextBox()
        {

        }
        public static  DependencyProperty CaretIndexProperty =DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "CaretIndex",typeof(int),typeof(CustomTextBox),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
        public static void SetCaretIndex(UIElement element, int value)
        {
            element.SetValue(CaretIndexProperty, value);
        }
        public static int GetCaretIndex(UIElement element)
        {
            return (int)element.GetValue(CaretIndexProperty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should post some code of how you do binding in xaml and your property

Comment: Is `Text` property of `CustomTextBox` a DependencyProperty (it seems it is)? Post the relevant code from `CustomTextBox`.

Comment: i didnt attach that property.

Comment: I only attach CaretIndex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Text="{Binding Path=MainTxtBoxText,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
<cstmTxtBox:CustomTextBox Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" x:Name="TxtBox" cstmTxtBox:CustomTextBox.CaretIndex="{Binding Path=CaretIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Path=MainTxtBoxText,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   >
```

By default text box update view model on focus lost. Specifying UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged will update view model every time text in text box changes.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing `UpdateSourceTrigger` property in your code which specifies how the change to data should reflect in the model property. To elaborate, `UpdateSoruceTrigger` property has four options to select from :-

**Default** - which returns the default UpdateSourceTrigger value of the target dependency property. It varies with control.

**LostFocus** - Changes reflect when focus move away from the current control.

**PropertyChanged** - reflect changes as soon as data changes. For a textbox, whenever a key is pressed, the changes occur.

**Explicit** - As the name suggests, it occurs on your command. you must call the UpdateSource method or the changes will not propagate back to the source